# Attribute mapping with a Python property

Tags: python

Is there a way to make a Python `@property` act as a setter and getter all at once?

I feel like I've seen this somewhere before but can't remember and can't recreate the solution myself.

For example, instead of:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, b): self.b = b
  def get_c(self): return self.b.c
  def set_c(self, value): self.b.c = value
  c = property(get_c, set_c)
```

we could somehow signal that for `A` objects, the `c` attribute is really equivalent to `b.c` for getter, setter (and deleter if we like).

### Motivation:

This would be particularly useful when we need `A` to be a proxy wrapper around `B` objects (of which `b` is an instance) but share only the data attributes and no methods. Properties such as these would allow the `A` and `B` objects' data to stay completely in sync while both are used by the same code.

Comment: The question here is what's special about your proxy delegation case that makes it different from the typical case where you'd use `__getattr__` and friends? If it's just "dynamic delegation to data but not methods", just do the usual dynamic delegation and filter on, e.g., `callable`.

Comment: Though interesting that still doesn't solve the original concern I had about being able to document to the end-user what it was they could interact with. In the case of the well defined mapping `a.c --> a.b.c`, `a.d --> a.b.d`, `a.e --> a.b.special_e`, etc. it seems using a `dict` or `list` is preferable to filtering on `callable`, but also `setattr` would have to do a lookup first (to make sure not `callable`) before setting the value.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment. Are you saying it would be better to have an explicit `list` of attributes to forward, instead of forwarding everything that's not callable? If so, sure, in a lot of cases, that's better. It depends on how dynamic/generic your use case is. If you add a new attribute to `b`, should it appear in `a`? If so, use a dynamic filter; if not, use a static whitelist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [this forwardTo class](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/510402-attribute-proxy-forwarding-attribute-access/) as posted on ActiveState.

> This recipe lets you transparently forward attribute access to another
>   object in your class. This way, you can expose functionality from some
>   member of your class instance directly, e.g. foo.baz() instead of
>   foo.bar.baz().

```
class forwardTo(object):
    """
    A descriptor based recipe that makes it possible to write shorthands
    that forward attribute access from one object onto another.

    >>> class C(object):
    ...     def __init__(self):
    ...         class CC(object):
    ...             def xx(self, extra):
    ...                 return 100 + extra
    ...             foo = 42
    ...         self.cc = CC()
    ...
    ...     localcc = forwardTo('cc', 'xx')
    ...     localfoo = forwardTo('cc', 'foo')
    ...
    >>> print C().localcc(10)
    110
    >>> print C().localfoo
    42

    Arguments: objectName - name of the attribute containing the second object.
               attrName - name of the attribute in the second object.
    Returns:   An object that will forward any calls as described above.
    """
    def __init__(self, objectName, attrName):
        self.objectName = objectName
        self.attrName = attrName
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        return getattr(getattr(instance, self.objectName), self.attrName)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(getattr(instance, self.objectName), self.attrName, value)
    def __delete__(self, instance):
        delattr(getattr(instance, self.objectName), self.attrName)
```

For a more robust code, you may want to consider replacing `getattr(instance, self.objectName)` with `operator.attrgetter(self.objectName)(instance)`.  This would allow `objectName` to be a dotted name (e.g., so you could have `A.c` be a proxy for `A.x.y.z.d`).

Comment: Thanks for this. Great call on the `operator.attrgetter` too. My use case is not that broad, so it isn't needed, but it's certainly part of a general solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to delegate a whole slew of properties from any A object to its `b` member, it's probably easier to do that inside `__getattr__`, `__setattr__`, and `__delattr__`, e.g.:

```
class A(object):
    delegated = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in A.delegated:
            return getattr(self.b, attr)
        raise AttributeError()
```

I haven't shown the `__setattr__` and `__delattr__` definitions here, for brevity, and to avoid having to explain the difference between `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) if you need more information.

This is readily extensible to classes that want to proxy different attributes to different members:

```
class A(object):
    b_delegated = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    x_delegated = ['y', 'z']
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in A.b_delegated:
            return getattr(self.b, attr)
        elif attr in A.x_delegated:
            return getattr(self.x, attr)
        else:
            raise AttributeError()
```

If you need to delegate *all* attributes, dynamically, that's almost as easy. You just get a list of `self.b`'s attributes (or `self.b.__class__`'s) at init time or at call time (which of the four possibilities depends on exactly what you want to do), and use that in place of the static list `b_delegated`.

You can of course filter this by name (e.g., to remove `_private` methods), or by type, or any arbitrary predicate (e.g., to remove any `callable` attributes).

Or combine any of the above.

At any rate, this is the idiomatic way to do (especially dynamic) proxying in Python. It's not perfect, but trying to invent a different mechanism is probably not a good idea.

And in fact, it's not really meant to be perfect. This is something you shouldn't be doing too often, and shouldn't be trying to disguise when you do it. It's obvious that a `ctypes.cdll` or a `pyobjc` module is actually delegating to something else, because it's actually useful for the user to know that. If you really need to delegate most of the public interface of one class to another, and don't want the user to know about the delegation… maybe you don't need it. Maybe it's better to just expose the private object directly, or reorganize your object model so the user is interacting with the right things in the first place.

Comment: RE: Decorating a pair of functions. Check out the updates to `@property` in Python 2.6, for example, you can decorate a method `f` with `@property` and then decorate another method (which must **also** be called `f`) with `@f.setter` to accomplish these things.

Comment: RE: Using `__getattr__`. This was my current approach and I was starting to think that carrying around `delegated` was hard to document (I needed a custom `__dir__`, for example) and I was looking for alternatives.

Comment: @bossylobster: Ah, you're right, I forgot about those changes. I played with the new toy when it came out, but never really found a use for it, and forgot about it. Anyway, what is the actual problem with the usual delegation pattern with __getattr__ that you're trying to solve?

Comment: RE: Your code. No setters have been implemented, so the data is in sync in only one direction. `__getattr__` isn't called if the attribute is in `__dict__` hence if the user set the value, this delegation would be irrelevant after the fact.

Comment: @bossylobster: I only implemented `__getattr__` for brevity, because I assumed you'd be able to figure it out from the sentence talking about the three functions directly above. Do you really need me to implement examples of all three?

Comment: @abamert Not at all, I wasn't sure the reason, thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 3):

There's the [decorator syntax for creating properties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), then there are full blown [custom-defined descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), but since the setter/getter pseudo-private pattern is actively discouraged in Python and the Python community, there isn't really a widely distributed or commonly used way to do what you are looking for.

For proxy objects, you can use `__getattr__`, `__setattr__`, and `__getattribute__`, or try to manipulate things earlier in the process by fooling around with `__new__` or a `metaclass`.

Comment: Per your "actively discouraged" comment, is using the approach of @proppy part of this discouragement? I found that using the `__*attr__` approach was hard to document; e.g. as I mention in another comment, I had to implement `__dir__` in order to make the object user friendly.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you mean by "user friendly". Most dynamic proxies _don't_ implement `__dir__`—often because the true result would be too large, or too dynamic, or too slow to compute. But really, people don't expect it.

Comment: Well, one thing, if a user needs `__dir__` for anything other than hacking around, 99.9% of the time, their code is the problem not yours.  If you could tag the attributes you want to proxy somehow, perhaps via a class attribute listing them, a decorator, or a custom descriptor, you could then write a set of generic `__*attr__` methods that could just shadow the MRO and inspect all the proxied objects for their tagged attributes.

Answer (score 1):

```
def make_property(parent, attr):
  def get(self):
    return getattr(getattr(self, parent), attr)
  def set(self, value):
    setattr(getattr(self, parent), attr, value)
  return property(get, set)

class A(object):
  def __init__(self, b): self.b = b
  c = make_property('b', 'c')
```

Comment: Presumably he wants to actually define his own getter and setter functions, and then wrap them in a property. If you just want generic automatically-generated getter and setter functions… what's the point in the first place? Just use an attribute.

Comment: I can see value. If instead of the `getattr(getattr(...), ...)` mess, if you knew specifically that you wanted `c`, `d`, `e`, `f` and `g` on `A` objects to come from `b`, then something like `make_b_property` with `getattr(self.b, name)` and `setattr(self.b, name, value)` could be somewhat useful and would reduce the amount of code, which is Pythonic :)

Comment: It didn't seemed to like he wanted to define his own getter/setter functions, since he said: > if we could somehow signal that for A objects, the c attribute is really equivalent to b.c for getter, setter.

Comment: @bossylobster: Why? You don't need any of that getattr mess; you can just declare A.c the normal way and access it as A.c.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it, statically forwarding properties from one object to another, but with economy.

It allows to forward get/set property in two lines, and aread-only property in one line, making use of dynamic property definition at the class level and lambdas.

```
class A:
    """Classic definition of property, with decorator"""
    _id = ""
    _answer = 42

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @id.setter
    def id(self, value):
        self._id = value

    @property
    def what(self):
        return self._answer


class B:
    obj = A()
    # Forward "id" from self.obj
    id = property(lambda self: self.obj.id,
                  lambda self, value: setattr(self.obj, "id", value))
    # Forward read-only property from self.obj
    what = property(lambda self: self.obj.what)
```